# Store and Access Each Radio Button Click

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I would like to store every radio button selection as an array.

For example, given 2 radio buttons, if a user a selects the first, then the second, then the first again, I would like an array of `[1,2,1]`.

Here is `questions.html`:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>Question {{ post.Number }}</h1>
        <h2> {{ post.Question }}</h2>
            {% for choice in post.Choices %}
    <form>
                <input type="radio" name="choice" id="{{ post.Number }}{{ choice[0] }}" value="{{ choice[0] }}"> {{ choice[1] }}</input><br>
            {% endfor %}
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is `flask_main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import statics
app = Flask(__name__)

post = [
    {'Number': '1',
     'Statement': 'the question',
     'Choices': [('a', 'words'),
                 ('b', 'words')]
     },
    {'Number': '2',
     'Statement': 'the question',
     'Choices': [('a', 'words'),
                 ('b', 'words')]
     }
       ]

@app.route('/')
@app.route("/questions")
def questions():
    return render_template('questions.html', posts=post)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is not related to the server-side (= Python).

First, make sure all the radio buttons are inside a single form otherwise they will be considered as being in a different group (AKA it will be possible to select more than one).

Then you can create an array, and inside the `change` event add the `id` (or whatever you want to store) of the modified radio to the array.

Now it is just a matter of what you are doing with the array. Display it somewhere on the page or send it back to the server.

See the example below in pure JS.

```js
let choices = [];
let radios = document.getElementsByClassName("my-radio");

for (let radio of radios) {
  radio.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    choices.push(event.target.id);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = choices;
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>Question 1</h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" class="my-radio" name="choice" id="question-1" value="choice-1">
    choice 1
  </input>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="my-radio" name="choice" id="question-2" value="choice-2">
    choice 2
  </input>
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I'm looking for! I will try implementing it now and be back with Qs. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can you help me with sending the array back to the server?